# read-only rest service on github

Tags: rest, github, jekyll, readonly, github-pages

i'm wondering if it's possible to use a github repository, especially the project pages branch combined with jekyll as a read-only rest service.

Does anyone got some experiences with this?

Or maybe a other solution? (github only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST stands for Representational State Transfer. A read-only site, by definition, can't perform state transfer. If you wanted to use GitHub pages to host JSON or XML documents that can be retrieved with HTTP GET requests, then that could conceivably work, but that isn't REST.